# Execute Mutiple thread side by side

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to execute multiple thread side by side.
ex: There will be a simple counter method, the thread will access the method and will print the counter value. One thread should not wait for another thread to stop before starting.

A sample output [maybe]:

T1 1
T2 1
T1 2
T1 3
T1 4
T2 2
T1 5

I've no prior idea on multi-threading and just want to learn.

Comment: You've posted an "I want" but no question yet. Surely you've read tutorials on threading first, right? What specific step are you stuck on?

Comment: Starting thread side by side. For a counter 1-500 a higher priority thread should finish faster than a slower priority thread.

Comment: The best way to learn is to start doing.  There are millions of examples for simple multi-threaded code so I would start with some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the counter is shared you want something like this:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private int id;

    public ThreadTask(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public void run() {
        int local = 0;
        while((local = counter.incrementAndGet()) < 500) {
            System.out.println("T" + id + " " + local);
        }
    }
}

...

new Thread(new ThreadTask(0)).start();
new Thread(new ThreadTask(1)).start();
```

Otherwise, if you want a per-thread counter:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int counter = 0;
    private int id;

    public ThreadTask(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public void run() {
        while(counter < 500) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("T" + id + " " + counter);
        }
    }
}

...

new Thread(new ThreadTask(0)).start();
new Thread(new ThreadTask(1)).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really asked anything specific.  If you're just looking for a general example of a non-thread-safe counter being shared across two or more threads, here you go:

```
public class Counter extends Thread {
    private static int count = 0;

    private static int increment() {
        return ++count;  //increment the counter and return the new value
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int times = 0; times < 1000; times++) {  //perform 1000 increments, then stop
            System.out.println(increment());  //print the counter value
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Counter().start();   //start the first thread
        new Counter().start();   //start the second thread
        Thread.sleep(10000);     //sleep for a bit
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to sleep actually, since they are not daemon threads.

Comment: @Tudor - Yes, but some IDE's may clear/hide the console output when the program terminates.  That's the main reason why the `sleep()` is there.

Comment: The program won't terminate until all the threads have finished.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Yes, and a thread that just prints 1000 lines will finish in a few seconds at the very most.

Answer (score 0):

Without having an actual question....

I think you can just start multiple threads and get them to access a synchonised printCounter method.

Something like

```
public class MyRunnable implemetns Runnable {
   private SharedObject o
   public MyRunnable(SharedObject o) {
       this.o = o;
   }
   public void run() {
       o.printCounter();  
   }
}
```

then to start you can just do

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

etc

Then in your sharedObject method you want to have method that holds a variable which you can print. This method could increment the counter too.

Be warned though that the thread scheduler does not guarantee when threads are run.